Number of Inequivalent $2$-Colorings of $3\times3\times\ldots\times3$ hypercube
Let $H_n=\{-1,0,1\}^n$, a $3\times3\times\ldots\times3$ hypercube. A ''hyperrow'' is any 3 points that differ in only a single coordinate. A ''slice'' is the a subset of $H_n$ obtained by fixing one coordinate. A 2-coloring is an assignment of the letters $A,B$ to the points in $H_n$ such that no hyperrow is colored $AAA$ or $BBB$.
For example, if $n=2$, then a possible 2-coloring would be
$\begin{array}{ccc}A&A&B\\A&B&A\\B&A&A\end{array}$
Two 2-colorings $C_0,C_1$ are equivalent if $C_1$ can be obtained from $C_0$ by swapping the colors $A,B$, permuting three parallel slices, re-ordering the coordinates, or some combination of these operations. For example the following are equivalent 2-colorings for $n=2$:
$\begin{array}{ccc}A&A&B\\A&B&A\\B&B&A\end{array}\stackrel{\text{swap last two rows}}{\Rightarrow}\begin{array}{ccc}A&A&B\\B&B&A\\A&B&A\end{array}\stackrel{\text{swap first two columns}}{\Rightarrow}\begin{array}{ccc}A&A&B\\B&B&A\\B&A&A\end{array}\stackrel{\text{exchange A,B}}{\Rightarrow}\begin{array}{ccc}B&B&A\\A&A&B\\A&B&B\end{array}\stackrel{\text{swap coordinates}\\\text{(i.e. transpose)}}{\Rightarrow}\begin{array}{ccc}B&A&A\\B&A&B\\A&B&B\end{array}$
Question: How many inequivalent 2-colorings are there, as a function of $n$? What is the asymptotic growth of this quantity as $n\rightarrow\infty$?
Here are the values for the first few $n$:

$n=1$: 1
$n=2$: 3
$n=3$: 106?

For $n=1$, all possible 2-colorings are equivalent to $AAB$. For $n=2$, the three possible inequivalent 2-colorings are:
$\begin{array}{ccc}A&A&B\\A&B&A\\B&A&A\end{array}\quad,\quad\begin{array}{ccc}A&A&B\\A&A&B\\B&B&A\end{array}\quad,\quad \begin{array}{ccc}A&A&B\\A&B&A\\B&A&B\end{array}$
It is not hard to see that these are inequivalent, and that all 2-colorings are equivalent to one of these. For $n=3$, I wrote a program that exhaustively searched through all possible 2-colorings and found the inequivalent ones. Assuming no mistakes were made, the program found 106 2-colorings. Things got way too big to figure out even $n=4$ via a naive exhaustive search.

Loosely related: https://oeis.org/A361870

In terms of group actions, it is the number of $S_2\times(S_3\wr S_n)$-orbits of $[2]^{\large [3]^{\Large [n]}}$, where $[n]:={1,2,\cdots,n}$ and $\wr$ is the wreath product of permutation groups.
